# Not able to exit from virtual environment python django.(Tried Deactivate,source deactivate and exit nothing worked)

Tags: python, django, shell, virtualenv

I am trying to exit from the virtual environment which I have created for running my Django application. Now I am not able to exit from it. I have tried all the command deactivate, source deactivate, exit (just to make sure anything works in my case). I have even deleted all the virtual environments as I am not able to exit. But still, I am not able to exit from it.

Environment: Python 3.7.2 ( not anaconda), Windows OS

Thanks in advance.

below is the error message:

deactivate : The term 'deactivate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ deactivate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~

```
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (deactivate:String) [], CommandNotFoundE
```

xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deactivate is not a Python command but a shell command. You have to activate/deactivate terminal shell environment, not within Python shell.

Comment: Thanks for response Arryph.  I believe you are suggesting me to run this from shell, not from a python program. I am running this in command prompt as a shell command. I am not running it in python.

Comment: ohh okay, try running with path, for example `venv\Scripts\deactivate`. replace `venv` with virtual environment directory name.

Comment: It's not giving any response and didn't exit from the virtual environment.

Comment: can you please let us know, how are you making sure that virtual environment is not deactivated after running `deactivate` command

Comment: PS C:\ProgramData\Divya Mereddy\atom\mysite - Github-Django> PS\Scripts\deactivate
PS C:\ProgramData\Divya Mereddy\atom\mysite - Github-Django>  ..............AFter deactivate also its showing virtual environment name before my directory link. Also when I am running my python django program its giving me below error. " importError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your P
YTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment? "

Comment: yes, actually as you are not able to import django means you are out of the virtual environment. to make sure, running this command `python -m pip freeze` will list currently installed packages. if you are within virtual environment, you will have django package in that list.

Comment: I didn't install any packages in my virtual environment.I was running my Django application in my system python. But actually, I found my Django is not working in my system python now. So I fixed it. Right now Django application is working great. But still, I am able to see PS as prefix to my directly like this (PS C:\ProgramData\Divya Mereddy\atom\mysite - Github-Django>) .

Comment: Which basically represents we are in virtual environment right arryph?

Comment: yeah, that represents that some virtual environment is activated. but more important is which Python/pip/other Python scripts are actually in play, for example running `where python` will print out which Python executable is actually running, the system Python or from virtual environment Python

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your directory to scripts and deactivate.

Comment: I appreciate your response. Can you elaborate it a little bit please. I am new to these all

Answer (score 0):

What @BlackBoxSql sugeested worked for me.
In the terminal, type

```
cd C:\Users\John\hello_w\.venv\Scripts
```

and hit enter (use your correct directory). It then stated:

> Suggestion [3,General]: The command deactivate was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\deactivate". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCode, you can handle multiple environments by using the extension called `Python Environment Manager`, here is the [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python-environment-manager) to download it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ok, so after 2 hours I finally figured out how to set-up, activate and deactivate (and delete) my virtual environment, and this thread has been helpful. However, I want to add to the thread by @arryph and OP @Divya M which I think might contain some error. The 'PS' prefix that Divya is referring to in:

> But still, I am able to see PS as prefix to my directly like this (PS
> C:\ProgramData\Divya Mereddy\atom\mysite - Github-Django>)
> Which basically represents we are in virtual environment right arryph?

...might not be an indicator that the virtual environment is active, as it might only stand for PowerShell if that's what they're using.

If your virtual environment has been activated, you will see a prefix of your virtual environment name enclosed in parenthesis at the beginning of the prompt, right before PS if you're using PowerShell:

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\cole\Documents\automation>
```

in Powershell, (.venv) is green.

If this is not the case for you, you can try any of the following code that I got from another thread. The first one was what worked for me:

```
$ <virtual environment directory>\Script\activate
$ <virtual environment directory>\Script\Activate.psl
$ <virtual environment directory>\Script\Activate
```

note that I am on the root folder (automation) when running this.

the prefix should show up after running the command. For verification, you can check whether or not you're on the virtual environment by running the following command:

```
$ $Env:Path
```

(note the included $ in the command) And look for the directory of your virtual environment. Here's mine:

```
C:\Users\cole\Documents\automation_setup\.venv\Scripts;...
```

If you want to exit the virtual environment, it should be easy to just type in `deactivate` and the prefix will be gone.

You can run the command $Env:Path again and the path for your python should be back to the Python system path:

```
C:\Users\cole\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe;...
```

Hope this helps